# Eclipse update the statusbar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on Eclipse plugin and I add an 16x16 icon to the statusbar by

```java
ToolBarManager manager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.HORIZONTAL); 
manager.add(updatingNewsAction);
```

Where `updatingNewsAction` is a class that extends `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action`.

However I've got problem with removing the `updatingNewsAction` from the toolbar. It's removed, but I can see that only when something updates the statusbar - for example minimazing/maximazing the borderline views. Then after reading some blog post I've wrote:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
            IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

            IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();

            IWorkbenchPart part = page.getActivePart();
            IWorkbenchPartSite site = part.getSite();

            IViewSite vSite = (IViewSite) site;

            IActionBars actionBars = vSite.getActionBars();

            if (actionBars == null) {
                return;
            }
            IStatusLineManager statusLineManager = actionBars.getStatusLineManager();

            if (statusLineManager == null) {
                return;
            }
            statusLineManager.update(true);
        }
    });
```

Which is a step forward, because it gets updated when switching focus between views, but still it doesn't happen immediately and without user interactions. How to update the status bar programmatically immediately?

Comment: Are you calling `IStatusLineManager.update` when you remove your action?

Comment: I'm sorry, had to cut the last line from second listing. Yes, I call the update method with 'true' as 'force' parameter. Rarely it happens immediately, most often it's like I wrote - user need to switch focus between views to see the result.

Comment: If the update method is everything that can be done can you post it? I need to have this confirmed.